# Why is the edge of my object red?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

I have modeled a marble countertop here:

[image]

Upon rendering it however, there is a red lighting along the edges:

[image]

I am using the Cycles render engine. What settings do I need to enable/disable to avoid this red lighting from occurring?

I have attached the blender file below if you'd like to investigate:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've given *Subsurface Scaterring* to your marble material, you need to either lower it down to 0 or, in the *Subsurface Radius*, lower down the first value, it is the red color value that is scattered in the volume, the 2 other values are green and blue:

[image]